# Microsoft Access Control Source help in Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table, call it "Employees", that has a field in it called "Month".  This field is a lookup that is referencing another table called "MonthList".  The "MonthList" table looks like this:

```
MonthNumber MonthName
1           January
2           February
3           March
.
.
.
.
```

"MonthNumber" is there so I can sort the list in sequential order (sorting alphabetically won't work for months).

I have a form where I am displaying the field "Month" using a Text Box (the Control Source is "Month").  I have it set so the user can't select or change it (I'm using a Text Box so there is no dropdown arrow).  The issue is that it is displaying MonthNumber instead of MonthName.  I thought this would be a simple fix (and probably still is) but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas on changing the display to MonthName instead of MonthNumber?

Comment: What's the primary key of `MonthList`?

Comment: It's `MonthNumber`. Would it solve the problem if it was changed to `MonthName`?

Comment: Yes. Most easily. Otherwise you can do a `dlookup` to get the month name. But changing the PK is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Primary Key to MonthName works in this situation.